# Weird Lines when Dual Booting with Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, screen

So I recently decided to give Ubuntu a whirl, so I tried to dual boot it alongside windows 8.1. However, when put it on my USB and booted from there to install it. I immediately got yellow/orange vertical lines all over the screen and it appears as the screen is shifted to the left (right side of monitor is black and missing the left side).

To start, I am running Windows 8.1 on a 120GB SSD and also have a 1TB HDD. I created a new partition on my SSD to install Ubuntu on. Then I booted and installed and end up with this problem.

Any info or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with video adapter after fresh install, you need to boot with "nomodeset" boot parameter and after that install a proper video driver.

In some cases video adapters are not well supported by kernel drivers.

How to boot with "nomodeset" you can see [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850).